# Understanding mathematical representation of probability in terms of CDF and PDF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

In many research papers, I came across following form of probability expression as shown by equation (A) and (B).

$F_{\Upsilon}(\gamma)= \text{Pr}(Y\leq\frac{\gamma}{X})$---(A)

where both $Y,X$ are random variables and all others are constant.

Further, eq.(A) is expressed as

$F_{\Upsilon}(\gamma)= \int_0^{\infty}\text{Pr}(Y\leq\frac{\gamma}{x})f_X(x)$ ---(B)

My question is how (B) is obtained from (A).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: (B) cannot be obtained from (A) unless 1) $X$ has a density $f_X$ and  2) $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the problem is formulated as:

*$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with CDF's $F_X(x) = \text{Pr}(X\leq x)$, $F_Y(y) = \text{Pr}(Y\leq y)$, and PDF's $f_X(x) = F'_X(x)$, $f_Y(y) = F'_Y(y)$*.

*Find a CDF of a random variable $Z = XY$.*

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
F_Z(z) &= \text{Pr}(Z\leq z) = \text{Pr}(XY\leq z) = \text{Pr}\left(Y\leq\frac{z}{X}\right) = \\
&= \left[
\begin{array}{l}
\text{we have to sum up the probability values for all possible values of }X \Leftrightarrow\\
\text{integrate over domain of }X\text{ with respect to density }f_X(x). \text{ For example, if } X >0 : 
\end{array}\right] = \\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}\underbrace{\text{Pr}\left(Y\leq\frac{z}{x}\right)}_{=F_Y\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)}f_X(x)dx = \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty}F_Y\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)f_X(x)dx
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you sir for such a detailed answer.

Comment: Sir, suppose we have the situation like $Z = XY+A$ where $X,Y$ and $A$ are independent random variables with their  CDF as $F_X(x), F_Y(y), F_A(a) $ and PDF as $f_X(x), f_Y(y), f_A(a) $  then  can we write like this:  $F_Z(z) = \text{Pr}(Z\leq z) = \text{Pr}(Y \leq \frac{z}{X}-\frac{A}{X}) = \int_o^{\infty}\int_o^{\infty} \text{Pr}(Y \leq \frac{z}{x}-\frac{a}{x}) f_X(x) f_A(a) \text{d}x\text{d}a$

Comment: Can we write as mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, we can write as you suggest. Another way is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Pr}(XY+A \leq z) &= \text{Pr}(A\leq z-XY) = \int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}\text{Pr}(A\leq z- xy)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy = \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}F_A(z- xy)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Ok sir. I think your answer is correct if our interest is to find probability of $A$. If we have to find probability of $Y$ then the way I had written is correct. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Not exactly correct.

You have a random variable $Z = XY+A$, Your tsk is to find $F_Z(z) = \text{Pr}(Z \leq z)$, which is equivalent to any of the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Pr}(Z \leq z) &= \text{Pr}\left(XY + A \leq z\right) = \\
&= \text{Pr}\left(X \leq \frac{z}{Y} -\frac{A}{Y}\right) =  \\
&= \text{Pr}\left(Y \leq \frac{z}{X} -\frac{A}{X}\right) = \\
&= \text{Pr}\left(A \leq z -XY\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You are not looking _ **...for a probability of $Y$...**_, you are looking for a probability of $Z\leq z$, which, in this case, is equivalent to one of the above.

Comment: Understood sir. Thank you so much for your whole hearted support.

Comment: Sir, suppose we have the situation like: $\text{Pr}\biggl( XY \leq \frac{\gamma_{th}(\mu_3 Z+\mu_4)}{\zeta-\frac{\gamma_{th}\mu_1}{Y}-\frac{\gamma_{th}\mu_2}{X}}\biggr)$ where $X,Y,Z$ are independent random variables having CDF $F_X(x), F_Y(y), F_Z(z)$ and PDF $f_X(x), f_Y(y), f_Z(z)$ and all other things are constant, then can we represent it like this: $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \text{Pr}\biggl( XY \leq \frac{\gamma_{th}(\mu_3 Z+\mu_4)}{\zeta-\frac{\gamma_{th}\mu_1}{Y}-\frac{\gamma_{th}\mu_2}{X}}\biggr) f_X(x) f_Y(y) f_Z(z) \text{d}x \text{d}y \text{d}z $?